# Spring Integration Jdbc StoredProcMessageHandler Pretty Log Procedure Request and Response

Tags: spring-integration

Tried enabling `DEBUG` in `CallMetaDataContext`, however need to find a way to pretty print the Stored Proc `IN` and `OUT` parameter with values. Please suggest

Also, would it be considered OK / acceptable if we use `.handle("someBean", "someMethodUsingJdbcTemplate")` instead of `StoredProcMessageHandler`. The reason is former helps me with pretty logging using `JdbcTemplate`

**Pretty Logging using JdbcTemplate:**

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    // @formatter:off
    simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName(STORED_PROC)
                                                    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess() // this is optional
                                                    .returningResultSet("REF_CURSOR_NAME_FROM_STORED_PROC", null); // this is optional
    // @formatter:on

    simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_PARAM_1", Types.VARCHAR));
    simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_PARAM_2", Types.VARCHAR));
}

private Map<String, Object> constructCallParams(final Object dtoObject) {

    Map<String, Object> callParams = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    callParams.put("IN_PARAM_1", dtoObject.field1());
    callParams.put("IN_PARAM_2", dtoObject.field2());

    return callParams;
}

public Mono<Void> fetch(final String request) {

    Map<String, Object> callParams = constructCallParams(null);

    // @formatter:off
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> simpleJdbcCall.execute(callParams))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .doOnError(ex -> log.error("{} InParams: {}, Exception: {}", STORED_PROC, callParams, ex.getMessage()))
                .onErrorMap(ApplicationException::new) // optional
                .flatMap(outParams -> {
                    log.info("{} InParams: {}, OutParams: {}", STORED_PROC, callParams, outParams);
                    return Mono.empty();
                });
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `handle()` for any custom method invocation - the service activator pattern. A `StoredProcMessageHandler` is just an out-of-the-box convenient for some use-case a service activator implementation. Please, share with us how you do that pretty logging using JdbcTemplate. Probably something like `public StoredProcExecutor(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {` to expose would be enough for you to keep that pretty logging and still use a `StoredProcMessageHandler`. Feel free to raise a GH issue about this new constructor!

Comment: Please see the update (sample in reactive way, but can be non-reactive as well with a try-catch), kindly confirm if the edit shall apply to Spring Integration as well. I will create a GH issue, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but that has nothing to do with `JdbcTemplate`. Your comment in the question is misleading. Yes, you can do that kind of logging yourself, but this is fully not related to any framework component. I don't see how exposing `JdbcTemplate` on the `StoredProcExecutor` would help over here, so no need in any issues.]